# Load jQuery prior to loading custom scripts, without using modules or multiple <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple script that I placed inside it's own file (my_file.js). This script **depends on jQuery**. Obviously users can access its functionality via the script tags inside the head tags:

```
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
<script src='my_file.js'></script>
</head>
```

This works perfectly, since the JS is loaded sequentially. But I would like users to **not have to add jQuery explicitly** at the top. Is there a way my_file.js can itself load jQuery prior to its own JS, such that users only add the one file:

```
<head>
<script src='my_file.js'></script>
</head>
```

I know modules and bundlers take care of this issue, but I'm interested to see if there is an approach that allows one file to bring in its dependency, and wait until it's loaded before running the rest of the script.

Is there something like **dynamic imports**, such that:

```
import('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js').then(module => {
  // load my scripts here
});
```

Or **AJAX** in vanilla JS:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js')
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // load my scripts here
    }
    else {
        console.log('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status)
    }

}
```

Everything I try runs my_file.js before jQuery. **How can I make sure jQuery is loaded first, without having to place it in the  tags?**

Answer (score 1):

Open [jquery.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js) on your browser. Select all code and then copy it. Then paste it to the beginning of `my_file.js`.

The code should like:

```
/*! jQuery v3.3.1 | (c) JS Foundation and other contributors | jquery.org/license */
!function(e,t){"use strict";"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=e.document?t(e,!0):function(e){if(!e.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return t(e)}:t(e)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(e,t){"use st.....

// Your code here...
```

Comment: What if it already exists and version you include is not compatible with version already existing?

Comment: @charlietfl jquery will not be initialized if its already initialized.

Comment: That is not true. When you load multiple versions they each overwrite the global object unless using `noConflict()`

Comment: @MisirJafarov I actually tried this first, but I get SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'function' .... which occurs after the first function of my own code.

Comment: @charlietfl you can insert jquery code inside  `if (window.jQuery == undefined) {  /* jquery.min.js */ }`

Comment: Yes but that was not mentioned which was exactly my original point. No point in loading the new one either if it already exists

Comment: @Cybernetic can you send me the code using pastebin.com? :/

Comment: @charlietfl this is not a duplicate....that approach does not wait for jQuery to finish loading prior to running custom script.

Comment: @Cybernetic the approved answer solves that by using `onload` . You can also use document.write if it doesn't exist as shown in another answer

Comment: @charlietfl yes I tried that...for some reason the code runs immediately...in fact, even if I use setTimeout with a significant delay the code runs immediately.

Comment: @Cybernetic not doing things right then